# Find color distance with deltaE_ciede2000 in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In python, I can use this code to determine the color distance between two images
but I have no idea how to do in with TensorFlow
(I already have a function to convert tensor from RGB to LAB color space)

```
from skimage.color import deltaE_ciede2000
import cv2

im1 = cv2.imread('image1.jpg')
im2 = cv2.imread('image2.jpg')
im1_lab = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB).astype(np.float32)
im2_lab = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB).astype(np.float32)
color_dist = deltaE_ciede2000(im1_lab, im2_lab).mean()
print('color distance:', color_dist)
```

Comment: Why do you have to do it with TensorFlow?  Won't you do all of this conversion before you feed anything into TensorFlow?

Comment: I have to other loss calculation for structural similarity (dssim) which requires RGB but I need to calculation the color difference too I just don't want to add more features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `deltaE_ciede2000` function in a [`tf.py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage.color import deltaE_ciede2000

a = tf.random.uniform((8,8,3))
b = tf.random.uniform((8,8,3))
color_dist = tf.reduce_mean(tf.py_function(deltaE_ciede2000, inp=[a,b], Tout=tf.float32))
```

Another solution is to re-implement the skimage function in TensorFlow, you can find the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/color/delta_e.py#L122-L244)